# Is it possible to transform this python code into a single line

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

Is it possible to transform this code into one single line?

```
for x in xrange(m):
    for y in xrange(n):
       e.append(c[y][x])
    f.append(''.join(e))
    e=[]
```

My incomplete solution:

```
e=[(c[y][x]) for x in xrange(m) for y in xrange(n)]
```

I don't know how to add the last two lines...
Is there a way to add those last two lines in my incomplete solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
f = [''.join(c[y][x] for y in xrange(n)) for x in xrange(m)]
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- generator expression for e
```

Your outer loop compiles `f`, not `e`. This also assumes that `f` and `e` are empty lists at the beginning of the outer loop. If you had been building a flat list with a nested comprehension, you would have had the scopes of the `for`-expressions right ;)